# Java List - Sorting by certain column e.g FirstName

Tags: java, list

What i would like to do is have a method that takes in a string which will be the column name and return a sorted list by that column

```
@Command(description="Get all Activities")
  public void getActivities (String sortedBy)
  {
    List<Activity> activityList = new ArrayList<Activity> (paceApi.getActivities());
    // Sort by Parameter
    IASCIITableAware asciiTableAware = new CollectionASCIITableAware<Activity>(activityList, "firstname", "lastname", "email"); 
    ASCIITable.getInstance().printTable(asciiTableAware);
  }
```

Is there a Collections method that can do this or is there another way?

Thanks

Comment: I might be reading it wrong but it doesn't seem to account for the multiple fields. It assumes that you are always sorting by the same field.

Comment: @user237468: Same principle, if you understand how comparator works then all you need is a switch on the sortedBy parameter and change the comparator logic accordingly